# MySQL cluster DataMemory and DiskPageBufferMemory parameters

Tags: mysql, configuration, ndbcluster, mysql-cluster

I want to setup a MySQL cluster.

- The amount of data is more than double the amount of RAM.
- I have 3 Data Nodes each with 8GB RAM.

## QUESTIONS

- What is a good rule for the DataMemory and DiskPageBufferMemory parameters?
- Are 3GB DiskPageBufferMemory and 2GB DataMemory good values?

Answer (score 2):

## DISCLAIMER : Not SCMCDBA Certified

If you plan to hold data in memory, you need to

- increase RAM on all data nodes to 16GB
- increase the DataMemory to 6GB
- increase the number of SQL nodes to 3 (Makes SQLNodes to DataNodes 1:1)

If you cannot make these changes, then you should offload data to local storage

- [MySQL Cluster -- Storing table data on data nodes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/mysql-cluster-storing-table-data-on-data-nodes)

Here is one of the best answers from Frazer Clement : [MySQL Cluster RAM requirement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9357/mysql-cluster-ram-requirement/10464#10464)

He states in his answer

> When configuring DataMemory and IndexMemory, it is best to limit yourself to somewhat less than the physical memory in each system. Some physical memory should be reserved for the OS and other processes.

There are three MySQL Cluster Gurus in this forum

- [Frazer Clement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4981/frazer-clement)
- [Mat Keep](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4224/mat-keep)
- [Andrew Morgan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4223/andrew-morgan)

Checks out their answers !!!

Comment: What relation has amount of data and number of SQL nodes?

Comment: If SQL nodes and Data nodes are separate, then there is no relation. I would still raise the amount of RAM and assign bigger buffers is you do not plan to store any data to disk on the Data nodes.